# Use of regex in sublime text 3, Tex to Html

Tags: editors, html, sublime-text

In a job that I am doing, you must do tasks in a repetitive way by migrating articles in latex to html. I can not make substitutions using regex to replace command like

```
\textit{text}
```

to

```
<i> text </i>.
```

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Have you considered using [pandoc](http://pandoc.org/)? That software can output `html` code given `tex` code in input. It is simple to use, and extremely efficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I leave the solution you implement to make the substitutions when we have a phrase instead of a word.

```
\\textit\{(.+?)\}
\textit{Service Oriented Architecture}

<i>\1</i>
<i>Service Oriented Architecture</i>
```

I closed the question